# Aguardar retorno de Ajax em função síncrona

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma operação que preciso realizar de forma síncrona, mas parte das informações das quais preciso somente podem ser obtidas via Ajax.

Tentei tornar tudo síncrono com uma espera pelo retorno do Ajax. O problema é que enquanto qualquer função estiver executando, os eventos do Ajax que tratam do retorno com sucesso não são executados.

Isso é um exemplo do que estou a fazer:

```
function foo () {
    var a = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: "foo" // substitua por qualquer URL real
    }).done(function () {
        a = true;
    });

    while(!a) { } // Isto é apenas para se ter uma espera.
    alert(a); // Isso nunca vai executar
}
foo();
```

E isso tem me gerado uma `race condition`: a função associada ao evento `done` não executará enquanto o `while` estiver a iterar, e o `while` jamais terminará enquanto o evento `done` não for executado.

Existe alguma forma de se atingir meu objetivo?

Comment: Depende um pouco do que você quer fazer, mas __[pode sempre chamar uma função defenida fora](http://jsfiddle.net/ncSm4/)__ do `.done()` passando a resposta do ajax como parâmetro. Pode juntar mais código para percebermos melhor o seu problema?

Comment: já tentou levantar uma exceção se não houver resposta do servidor? dentro do while você testa se o tempo de espera for maior 5 * 60 * 1000  (5 minutos) caso verdadeiro então dispara uma exceção avisando que não houve resposta do servidor...

Comment: @Sergio o problema é simples... Apenas esperar, dentro de uma função síncrona, pelo retorno de uma chamada assíncrona. Quero forçar uma operação a ser síncrona. Coloquei um pouco mais de código apenas para ilustrar melhor.

Comment: @Renan juntei um jsFiddle ao meu comentário em cima. Opção é usar `async: false` como o bfavaretto sugeriu, tendo conta dos avisos e problemas que isso pode trazer.

Comment: @Renan O que te impede de chamar a uma função com o comportamento desejado dentro do done?

Comment: @LuizFilipe Nada, apenas quero realizar uma sequência inteira em um único método. Mas estou avaliando a melhor forma de fazer ainda. De qualquer forma, a resposta do bfavaretto foi na mosca.

Comment: Você já tentou uma solução de espera com o setInterval? http://jsfiddle.net/YnbL4/

Comment: @LuizFilipe vou tentar algo assim, ou transferir a lógica pro `done`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sim, mas em primeiro lugar preciso deixar claro que **usar ajax de forma síncrona é altamente contra-indicado**. A interface de usuário ficará congelada até o retorno do ajax.

O código para isso em jQuery é:

```
var a;
$.ajax({
    url: "foo", // substitua por qualquer URL real
    async: false
}).done(function () {
    a = true;
});
console.log(a);
```

O `while` não funciona pois ele está bloqueando a única *thread* usada em JS. Enquanto o código não sai do `while`, o *event loop* não avança, e os eventos assíncronos (o `done`/`complete` do ajax incluso) não são nunca processados. E assim o valor de `a` nunca muda, e o `while` nunca termina, é um loop infinito.

Comment: Agora me sinto mal por não ter lido o manual... `async: false` foi o pulo do gato mesmo.

Comment: Mas não custa insistir, @Renan: se você puder alterar o código para trabalhar de maneira assíncrona, faça isso.

Comment: Pode ter certeza de que farei :) Encontrei formas melhores de se resolver o meu problema aqui, mas ainda assim é interessante conhecer a opção síncrona pra chamada do método `ajax` do jQuery.

Comment: E eu como um bom noob fiz uma gambiarra imensa no meu projeto para executar o resto de uma função só depois que o ajax retornasse algo. Bendito StackOverflow.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Provavelmente você fez a coisa certa, ajax é feito para ser usado de maneira assíncrona.

Answer (score 3):

Já tentou utilizar callbacks?

```
function foo (callback) {
  $.ajax({
      url: "/minha_api",
      myCallback: callback,
      success: function(){
        this.myCallback(true);
      }          
  });     
}

foo(function(a){
   alert(a);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No ultimo caso, quando nada estiver funcionando:

```js
function foo () {
    var a = false;
    $.ajax({
        url: "foo" // substitua por qualquer URL real
    }).done(function () {
        a = true;
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        if (a) {
            alert(a); // Isso pode acontecer
        }
    }, 100);
}

foo();
```

Comment: "Isso ***pode*** acontecer"...