# Tempo de resposta do Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Pessoal tou fazendo o meu primeiro AJAX e estou tendo um problema que é o seguinte. Ele chama uma rotina em PHP que faz o download e upload via FTP de um ou varios arquivos. E isto pode demorar. Como eu faço para o AJAX ficar aguardando pois ele ta finalizando antes da resposta.

[Pastbin com o codigo](http://pastebin.com/HCCYqNu7)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6392/aguardar-retorno-de-ajax-em-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-s%C3%ADncrona mas não recomendo você utilizar ele dessa forma.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft ja coloquei o async=false e da na mesma ele retorna o valor do Data vazio. Se eu tento executar a url pelo POSTMAN que é uma extensão do Chrome para executar API Rest ele me retorna o JSON correto: {"status":true,"mensagem":"Planilha.pdf -> Enviado com sucesso. "}

Comment: Tá afinal qual você quer que espere, o $ajax ou o $post que você está usando?

Comment: $post, esqueci de comentar. Desculpe

Comment: $.post is asynchronous, you need to use $.ajax and set async to false, that way you will be able to wait for the response. You can read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575214/how-to-wait-for-response-in-post-jquery)

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft refiz o codigo e os 2 consoles que tem no codigo continuam retornando em branco. Agora eu tou percebendo que esta demorando mais para voltar a resposta. Veja o novo codigo: http://pastebin.com/eiv2Pd5P

Comment: Tem certeza que está indo para a URL correta, que está retornando alguma coisa ou que não está dando erro? Olhou seu console (f12 - Chrome) para ver se não há erros?

Comment: Chequei tudo, inclusive ele dispara a URL ela começa a fazer o download do arquivo e aborta. Ai eu testo ela via o POSTMAN e tudo certo ela faz o download e o upload corretamente e volta a mensagem de conclusao sem erros. Experimente ai cria uma rotina em PHP que demore tipo uns 30 segundos ou mais e veja que ele nao vai esperar.

Comment: Exatamente, pois ele aborta requisições que passam de 30 segundos. Isso é configuração do php não do javascript. No seu PHP tente colocar algo como: ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 segundos = 5 minutos (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: Eu acho que não pois se eu executo a rotina sem chamar o AJAX ela demora e faz tudo certinho. so quando eu chamo via o ajax que ela nao executa.

Comment: Tenta isso aqui então: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798196/ajax-request-max-execution-timing-out

Comment: Tentei e marquei o tempo com 12 segundos ele retornou a resposta vazia. No Chrome ele marcou 12,81 segundos de espera nesta chamada.

Comment: Não dá para pôres o AJAX a correr um ficheiro PHP que não precisa de resposta? ou então dá para mudar para websockets para a ligação ficar aberta?

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso você pode utilizar o parâmetro `timeout` para colocar um timeout maior que o padrão que acredito ser de 30 segundos.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/...',
  timeout: 600000,
  success: ...
});
```