# Jquery.get() como assíncrona ou síncrona?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou vi a documentação oficial [aqui](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) e não vejo falar que o valor padrão é assíncrona ou síncrona, não vejo exemplo de como utilizar ambos (no segundo código abaixo).

Sei que dessa forma funciona:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  async: false,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

O código a seguir não existe `async` ?

```
$.get( "test.cgi", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } )
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

O segundo código não sei se o valor padrão `async` está como `true` ou `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo Ajax por padrão é **assíncrono**. O método `$.get` é uma forma curta (*shorthand*) de `$.ajax` que usa o método GET e, por ser a forma curta, os únicos parâmetros são, conforme a documentação mencionada:

```
jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )
```

- URL: página a ser requisitada
- data: os valores a serem enviados ao servidor
- Função: esta função é o `success` caso a requisição tenha sido bem-sucedida
- dataType: tipo de dado esperado

Aí existem outros callbacks como `done`, `fail`, `always`, cada um com a sua função.

Se quiser usar `async: false` terá que usar o método padrão `$.ajax`. O que é nem recomendado conforme explicado **[nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6393/8063)**.

Comment: dvd `$.get()` foi removido `async false` ?

Comment: Nunca houve, não tem como passar essa opção no método $.get.

Answer (score 3):

## Explicação

Sim, o método [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) é assíncrono, ele é uma forma abreviada do código abaixo.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

De acordo com a documentação do método [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), podemos observar que o valor de `async`, é, por padrão, `true`.

Comment: E se eu quiser usar como `false` ?

Comment: Qual versão do jQuery você usa?

Comment: ,a mais recente

Comment: Com o $.get você só conseguirá alterar este comportamento com o ajaxSetup. (e.g. jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});), o que não é recomendável.