# Modal não funciona (AJAX síncrono)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, modal

Ao utilizar esse código JS, utilizando JQuery:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.visualizar').click(function(){
                $('#container').fadeIn(300);
            });
        });
        function visualizarDados(codContato){
            //↓ função do ajax para mandar informações para a modal.php
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "modal.php",
                data: {codigo:codContato},

                success: function(dados){ 
                    $('#modal').html(dados);
                }

            });
        }
```

A modal não funciona e é apresentado este erro no console do browser:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Pesquisei e falam tem algo a ver com o AJAX ser síncrono, mas como não tenho muita experiência em AJAX ou jQuery, não entendi como resolver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em nenhum lugar do seu código mostra que o AJAX é síncrono. O AJAX, por sua natureza, foi criado pra ser **assíncrono**, como representa seu próprio nome:

AJAX (***A***synchronous **J**avaScript **a**nd **X**ML), ou seja, *JavaScript e XML Assíncrono*.

Não é recomendado usar AJAX de forma síncrona, por isso os navegadores disparam essa mensagem no console ([veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6393/8063)). No jQuery, isso seria feito através da opção `async: true`, mas o seu código não mostra isso.

Provavelmente seu problema é outro, até porque o código dentro do `$(document).ready(function(){` nada tem a ver com a função `visualizarDados(codContato)`.