# Jquery POST com pausa no envio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia.
Preciso fazer vários POST usando Jquery, mas eles precisam ser enviados um por um, de forma pausada.

Exemplo: Seria enviado todos os dados da vistoria, depois todos os dados dos ambientes e assim por diante.

### Problema

Como o servidor tem limitação de caracteres no POST, não posso enviar tudo de vez, tem que ser enviado de forma pausada, e assim não corre o risco de perder nenhum registro.

### Problema da minha solução criada

Esses dados são enviados via celular, e por algum motivo as vezes não envia todos os dados.

### Meu código JS

Tentei criar uma função `sleep`:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

//ENVIO N1
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM vistorias WHERE codigo=?', [codigo], async function (tx, rsVistoria) {
      let rowsVistoria = rsVistoria.rows;
      for (var i = 0; i < rowsVistoria.length; i++) {
        $.post("https://url.com.br/arquivo.php", {
          acesso:'vistorias',
          codigo: rowsVistoria[i].codigo,
          fotoFachada: rowsVistoria[i].fotoFachada
        });
        await sleep(1000);
      }
    })


//ENVIO N2
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM vistorias_OUTRA WHERE codigo=?', [codigo], async function (tx, rsVistoria) {
      let rowsVistoria = rsVistoria.rows;
      for (var i = 0; i < rowsVistoria.length; i++) {
        $.post("https://url.com.br/arquivo.php", {
          acesso:'vistorias',
          codigo: rowsVistoria[i].codigo,
          fotoFachada: rowsVistoria[i].fotoFachada
        });
        await sleep(1000);
      }
    })
```

### Minha pretenção com o código acima

Fazer com que cada `FOR` aguarde 1 segundo, para enviar o outro registro. Depois que acabar o o FOR do `ENVIO N1`, passa para o `ENVIO N2`, e assim por diante.

Alguém teria uma sugestão melhor?

Comment: Não manjo de JQuery, não sei qual o retorno do post, se for uma `Promise` tu pode dar `await` nela, caso o retorno seja outro, tu pode encapsular numa `Promise`, definir como `async` e depois dar um `await`

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta documentação: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Não seria melhor desistir do sleep e usar o método `$.ajax` com a opção de `async: false`?

Comment: @Benilson como faço isso?

Comment: @Benilson Poderia postar um exemplo?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na resposta aceita desse link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6392/aguardar-retorno-de-ajax-em-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-s%C3%ADncrona

Comment: @Benilson eu coloco cada insert em uma `function foo () {` diferente?

Comment: Vou colocar como resposta, para você entender melhor

Comment: @Benilson Obrigado.

Comment: onde for $.post... você troca por $.ajax... e deixa de usar sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez esse seja um dos poucos casos em que se deva usar requisições ajax síncronas:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "https://url.com.br/arquivo.php",
        type: 'POST',
        async: false, // define que pára tudo até a requisição finalizar
        // dataType: 'html', // define um tipo de retorno, talvez json
        data: {
            acesso:'vistorias',
            codigo: rowsVistoria[i].codigo,
            fotoFachada: rowsVistoria[i].fotoFachada
        },
        success: function (response) {
           // faz alguma coisa ao finalizar alguma requisição
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Voltei. Só para entender. Serão 5 AJAX que irei criar, um para cada INSERT. O `async: false`, faz com que só passe para o proximo ajax, quando o atual terminar?

Comment: Sim, qualquer ação javascript só será executada após terminar a execução da requisição ajax.

Comment: Veja esse exemplo, é isso mesmo? https://jsfiddle.net/xetc2ak9/

Comment: Confesso que acho muito estranho esse método `tx.executeSql`, e não sei como ele funciona, você deixa a query no frontend acessível para o usuário ver? Os dados enviados na requisição de `ENVIO N1` são exatamente os mesmos de `ENVIO N2` conforme no código da pergunta?

Comment: O `tx.executeSql` é para manipular dados SQLite/WebSQL. Sobre o ENVIO N1, e ENVIO N2, supliquei com a mesma informação somente para informar que serão mais de um. Esse código JS está dentro do celular. E preciso enviar os dados que estão salvos no WebSQL para o o servidor online MySQL.

Comment: Então, o código do fiddle está exatamente igual ao código que postei, que fiz substituindo o da pergunta que postou, o funcionamento vai ser exatamente o mesmo de $.post, só que ele vai executar de forma ordenada, caso uma requisição leve meio segundo ou dois, não vai importar, ele só vai executar a próxima requisição após terminar a anterior. A única coisa que não sei como vai funcionar é `async function` do `tx.executeSql`.

Comment: O que seria melhor, continuar a usar o meu código ou usar o seu?

Comment: Você tem que testar, comenta o sleep e troca o $.post(... pelo $.ajax(....Caso não funcione, posta um novo comentário ou edita a pergunta informando que essa resposta não funcionou, que talvez alguém dê uma outra resposta que te ajude melhor.

Comment: Pesquisando em https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas, descobri que esse `async function` tem que ser modificado para `function`.

Comment: Benilson, tem um coisa muito interessante acontecendo! Isso no meu e no seu codigo. Supondo que o `ENVIO N1` tem registro no SQLite, mas o `ENVIO N2` não tem nenhum registro, o codigo para no `ENVIO N1` e não passa para o proximo. Adicionei um valor na tebela do `ENVIO N2` ai saiu do N1 para o N2, estranho isso! Sabe me dizer se precisa fazer mais algo?

Comment: Veja se pode me ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433520/ajuda-para-desvendar-erro-codigo-para-se-n%c3%a3o-tiver-registro-na-tabela-websql